# 1-C Bitrix не устанавливается Тайтл для вкладки

Tags: php, битрикс

Как установить тайтл на вкладке? перебробывал уже все способы не хочет ставиться и все :
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php"); 
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Продукция"); 
 и в шаблоне там где $APPLICATION->ShowTitle();, не показывает 
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Продукция"); и так пробывал и файл компонет настраивал через масив, не работает, подскажите еще

Comment: Битрикс - он такой - Битрикс :)  Поищи сперва место откуда он берет тайтл задай в .section потом на странице прям впиши, скорее всего у тебя какой-то компонент на странице его перетирает, тебе просто нужно найти кто.

Comment: Orange_shadow, да я это понимаю там просто столько файлов в этом Битриксе уже не знаю где рыть

Comment: Вот поэтому для меня Битрикс это ругательное слово :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Н - невнимательность , `<title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?></title>` - было
`<title><?=$APPLICATION->ShowTitle();?></title>` - надо